How to get rid of black streaks?
file  (I don't know how to upload a blender file with additional files, so I added a zip archive)
I have an animation of a bush with leaves (To make rendering easier I baked them in alembic
format)
But I noticed that black stripes appear periodically


simplified version of the material

How to solve the problem with black stripes?

I don’t think the title of this question accurately matches the question body. It isn’t so much how to make a leaf material, as fix the one you have, with which, as you mentioned, there are multiple problems, not just one. You might need to deal with these as individual issues and ask separate questions about them with details.

@TheLabCat That's why I asked that maybe I'll have to make the new material from scratch. But I don't know where to find a lesson for this.

Asked what? I don’t know what you mean. As for tutorials, this site isn’t for finding them. You can check the Blender manual for basic information, and use this for when you get stuck on something in particular, but you shouldn’t try to ask multiple questions at once, or use this site to substitute learning the basics. This looks like a very unique way of making a tree, where did you get it?

@TheLabCat I simplified the question

Just on a guess, I might remove the whole “Shader to RGB“ conversion node tail with the gradient and everything, as it doesn’t seem to be having any good effects and possibly is causing the bad ones. Try a plain green emission shader instead.

@TheLabCat do you mean this?

Ok, well, that didn't work. Hmm, Do those black areas look particularly crowded in solid view?

Note: The official way of sharing a blend file is with blend-exchange, and to have the external files included you need to pack them. I've got the blend via the method you used, though.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
